# Tips on storing 2D arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a 2 dimensional array like: [1,[a,b,c,d,e],2,3]

I have it stored in an SQL database and am trying to retrieve it in the same format.

However it currently comes out as: 1,a,b,c,d,e,2,3

Any tips on how to get it back to its original 2D array format?

If not, are there any tips on how to better store the original array (maybe with different separators) so it is easier to split on the way out.

Sorry if this is a silly question. I am new to SQL databases and storing arrays.

Comment: what is the datatype of the field? what sql database are you using?

Comment: The second array should probably be another table and the second field should be a reference to that table.

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak I am using MySQL. And unfortunately have it stored as VARCHAR for legacy reasons. I am assuming I should have stored it as an array datatype so it makes it easier to pull it out?

Comment: No, I would think storing it as a string in MySQL would be best. Try putting  it in JSON format (object literal, everything in double quotes). call JSON.stringify(object) to store it and JSON.parse(object) when you get it. you can keep the datatype as varchar. Does your project have any helpers or are your api calls being parsed in any way?

Comment: Thank you all for the quick responses. I think the second table is the best option for my current set up. The only reason I think storing it as a JSON string wont work for me is because I don't know how long the internal array (alphabetical in the above example) will actually be, so I'm afraid the character length in my table will be breached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second array should probably be another table and the second field should be a reference to that table.

Table A
Row1 : id | 1 | table2Id | 3 | 4

Table B
Row1 : id | a | b | c | d

Comment: Thank you Anastasios, I will give this a go shortly.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that some part (of datatabase or mapper) is a using toString performing for every array. After formatting, the arrays are gone.

You might consider to use a [JSON](http://json.org/) data format and convert the array first with [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and store the plain string in the database.

After fetching from the database, you could convert it back to an array or object with [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).